# How Can I Improve This Script?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm learning shell scripting, and am finding it hard finding a good way to learn. I have created a script below which lets the user search various different Internet engines through options. I would be really grateful if someone could look through this and point out what I'm doing wrong, how to improve it, etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

## Get user search-engine option
while getopts aegwy: OPTIONS ; do
  case "$OPTIONS" in 
    a) ENGINE="http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss/?field-keywords";;
    e) ENGINE="http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw";;
    g) ENGINE="http://www.google.com/search?q";;
    w) ENGINE="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?search";;
    y) ENGINE="http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query";;
    ?) ERRORS=true;;
  esac
done &>/dev/null

## Ensure correct command usage
[ $# -ne 2 ] || [ $ERRORS ] && printf "USAGE: $(basename $0) [-a Amazon] [-e eBay] [-g Google] [-w Wikipedia] [-y YouTube] \"search query\"\n" && exit 1

## Ensure user is connected to the Internet
ping -c 1 209.85.147.103 &>/dev/null ; [ $? -eq 2 ] && printf "You are not connected to the Internet!\n" && exit 1

## Reformat the search query
QUERY=`printf "$2" | sed 's/ /+/g'`

## Execute the search and exit program
which open &>/dev/null ; [ $? -eq 0 ] && open "$ENGINE"="$QUERY" &>/dev/null && exit 0 || xdg-open "$ENGINE"="$QUERY" &>/dev/null && exit 0 || printf "Command failed!\n" && exit 1
```

Thanks in advance everyone, means a lot!

Comment: Is it working as expected? The `[...] && ...` stuff is a bit hard to read, maybe consider using `if` instead. Other than that, this seems okay...

Comment: it works fine, but I don't know if there's a better way to do it, thanks for your response

Comment: One of the gurus might come up with something, but this looks about right. Your `y` option looks like it wants a value, and the `[...] &&` stuff would be more readable as `if [...]`, but otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: i'll probably change to if statements now, what do you mean the y option wants a value? thanks again

Comment: IIRC, in the "aegwy:" after  `getopts`, the `:` after `y` means `y` wants a value. Also, I just half-remembered something about `getopts` vs `getopt`... I think `getopt` is supposed to be preferred, but I can't remember why. Maybe google "getopt vs getopts."

Comment: Did not know that about the colon! Learn something every day! I googled it, getopts is preferred over getopt. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, can you share that link with me? I've been using getopt, I think it's stricter somehow, and I have a man page for it, but not getopts.

Comment: http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/getopts.1.asp, getopts is a shell built in, I think that's why there's no man page

Comment: Whoa, `getopts` is in Windows? Crazy... thanks for the link.

Comment: Your usage statement is confusing, as it appears that the user is to type: '-a Amazon' rather than indicating that a naked '-a' indicates that the url to use is www.amazon.com.  It should read "$( basename $0 ) [-aegwy ]\n\noptions:\n\t-a  Amazon\n\t-e  ebay"  or something along those lines.

Comment: This kind of question is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best posted in codereviews, as indicated above, but here are some mostly stylistic comments.  I should stress that the script is pretty much fine as-is; these are just minor improvements that I think will help make the code easier to read/maintain, more robust in a couple cases, etc.

You don't need to use all-caps for variable names just because environment variables are all-caps; shell variables and environment variables aren't the same thing.

Since your `$OPTIONS` variable only holds one option at a time, a singular name would be better (e.g. `$option`).  Or you could go with `$opt`, which is somewhat traditional here.

The `:` in your getopts string (`aegwy:`) indicates that the `-y` option expects an argument, as in `-y`*something* instead of just `-y` by itself.  Since you aren't doing anything with `$OPTARG`, I'm guessing that's not intentional.

As others have said, an `if`/`then`/`elif`/`else` would probably be clearer than the chain of `&&` and `||`.

The test `[ $ERRORS ]` is somewhat unclear because it can mean a lot of different things depending on the content of the `$ERRORS` parameter.  A more explicit indication that you only care about whether or not it's set would be `[ -n "$ERRORS" ]`.

Comparisons like `[ -ne ]` and friends are mostly holdovers from before the shell had built-in integer arithmetic; the more modern idiom would be `(( $# != 2 ))`.

Your usage message implies that the -a, -e, -g, -w, and -y options take arguments of the form Amazon, eBay, Google, etc.  It would be clearer what the actual syntax of the command is without those additions; you can include an extra paragraph in the help text listing what each option stands for.

As a rule, error messages should go to stderr instead of stdout (`>&2`).

It's fine to use `basename $0` for consistency of output, but there's something to be said for leaving `$0` alone as it will reflect however the user actually invoked the command.  Something to consider.

Not much point in using `printf` if you're not using a format string; just use `echo`, which automatically appends the newline.   Usage messages traditionally don't include quotation marks, either; it's up to the user to quote the arg or not depending on whether it's needed.

Checking a command for success is exactly how `if` works, so there's no need to do explicit checks of `$?` unless you really care about the exact exit value.  In the case of your connectivity ping, you probably don't care about why it failed, only that it did:

```
  if ! ping -c 1 209.85.147.103 >/dev/null; then 
     echo >&2 "$0: You are not connected to the Internet!"
     exit 1
  fi
```

Your search query reformat might need to do more than just turn spaces into plus signs; what if it has an ampersand?  But if you're just doing the spaces-to-pluses thing, you could use bash parameter expansion do it without sed: `QUERY="${QUERY// /+}"`

If your program relies on open/xdg-open etc, you should probably check for its availability at the top; no sense doing anything else if you know you can't possibly perform the requested operation anyway.   And you can use a variable so you don't wind up repeating yourself in multiple clauses:

```
open=
for cmd in open xdg-open; do
   if type -p "$cmd" >/dev/null; then
     open="$cmd"
     break
   fi
done
if [ -z "$open" ]; then
   echo >&2 "$0: open command not found."
   exit 1
fi
```

And then later you can finish up with just this one line:

"$open" "$ENGINE=$QUERY" &>/dev/null

Comment: thanks very much for an extremely detailed answer. will definitely make a lot of all this. i in particular like the parameter expansion, much easier than using sed. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

http://linuxcommand.org/ is an excellent resource to improve your bash scripting skills.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ is another great document.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please explain why this answer was downvoted.  The original poster said "I'm learning shell scripting, and am finding it hard finding a good way to learn.", these are excellent resources to learn from.  So if this is not a good answer I'd like to know why.

Comment: Answers consisting of a couple of links only are discouraged; that could have been a comment. Leaving aside that the question is a bit off-topic on StackOverflow, the poster asked for comments about their code, not just links to programming guidelines. P.S. I'm not the downvoter :)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to add comments yet so answering a question is the only way to provide feedback for now.

Comment: That will change as soon as you provide a couple of correct, on-topic answers or ask some interesting questions: you need [50 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) to comment. I'd recommend to restrain from posting comment-like answers in the meantime: people will downvote without considering if you can comment. Good luck :) P.S. Also, see this guide on [how to answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question).